# Whos OIS rate? Is there only one?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, interbank-rates

I have a hard time understanding the OIS rate. My understanding is that this is the rate someone is willing to exchange federal funds rate over say 10 years to someone else. For example, some bank pay the floating rate a company gets in the markets for 10 years and the company pays a fixed rate on the same amount on some period to the bank.(this is just netted in the end)

But everyone has a different credit rating. Hence someone should pick a higher rate to swap interest payments with a riskier counterparty.

What is this swap rate then or "OIS rate"?

Comment: The underlying swap is collateralized, the credit risk is hence sufficiently small to be taken out of the picture for valuation.

Comment: @Kermittfrog collateralized with what? a treasury?

Comment: Cash or selected cash instruments

Comment: @Kermittfrog so this collateral weigh up both credit risk and the worse rate the counterpart might have?

Comment: The collateral is there to reduce the counterparty credit risk. It is reimbursed at a collateral rate/ price alignment interest, e.g. at SOFR (USD).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, OIS stands for overnight index swap. RFR (risk free rate) is the current acronym ISDA, central banks and regulators use for the indices in IBOR transition.

Therefore, OIS can be Fed Funds (FF) or SOFR for USD, and also can be ESTR or EONIA for EUR. So there is not just one. Credit ratings play "no" role here. [BoJ has argued](https://www.boj.or.jp/en/paym/market/sg/rfr1603c.pdf) that
embedded O/N default risk is negligible. That said, there is still the distinction between secured and unsecured rates.

For example a "traditional" FF OIS is a Fixed-Float swap, with the float leg referencing the FED Funds effective rate (EFFR). It resets daily and pays annually. The quote is the fixed leg that makes it a fair swap. You have a liquid market for quotes in these swaps. E.g. if you use Bloomberg, you can find the respective curves on `ICVS` (`ICVS 42` is the "traditional FF OIS, `ICVS 490` the SOFR OIS (RFR), `ICVS 133` EUR OIS and `ICVS 514` is ESTR).

In terms of what is used more frequently, the market (USD biased answer) is using SOFR discounting for all sorts of quotations now. For example, swaption vol is quoted with SOFR discounting, [CME](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/files/discounting-transition-proposal-aug-2020.pdf) and LCH moved to SOFR PAI and discounting on [Oct. 16 2020](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/microsites/arrc/files/libor-timeline.pdf) on new AND legacy swaps. For EUR cleared, major CCPs did this since July 27 2020.

The market switched to discounting with the relevant RFR rates on the dates above. Hence, if you have a dual stripped curve (e.g. 3m US Libor), you use SOFR and no longer OIS (FF).

While CCP's have switched to RFR discounting on SOFR/ESTR, many CSA's in OTC trading still reference FF/EONIA.  I suppose both will co-exist for (quite) some time.

In terms of credit risk post Libor, there are credit sensitive benchmarks being developed.

- [ICE's Bank Yield Index](https://www.theice.com/iba/bank-yield-index)
- [Bloomberg's BSBY Index](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/bloomberg-confirms-its-bsby-short-term-credit-sensitive-index-adheres-to-iosco-principles-301263169.html)

For example, [BSBY-SOFR](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-05-03/bofa-jpmorgan-enter-swaps-trade-tied-to-new-libor-replacement) basis swap already started to trade.

Comment: Thanks! So the rate is not, say a particular rate, that some explicit corporation get. But rather the rate that the bank is willing to sell via the swap, the swap in turn has different prices, but the imbedded rate is the same among all swap?

Comment: There is no difference between the swap and the rate really. The rate is the (quoted) fixed rate (coupon) of the swap. A swap itself is zero cost at initiation. The rate is such set in a way that this is the case.

Comment: But then the rate is not uniform? If Apple wants to trade its rate float which is say 1.4 % and ATNT which gets  3% and has different rating then shoult this effcect the rate or price? The Bank has to pay for in rate for ATNT..also if they defult then the bank is stuck with paying 3 % and gets 0. It should thus be a function of both the float of the corporation and its rating.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a credit rating of a firm. It's typically cleared or collateralized). The float rate is the OIS index (FF or SOFR). Just alike a Libor float is simply Libor, and does not change if you are Apple or someone else. You agree to swap something. Here it is for example SOFR against Fixed rate. So you either pay fixed or SOFR and receive the other. Maybe [this](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/markets/021815/introduction-ois-discounting.asp) helps a bit.

Comment: I thought the bank swapped their 10 year OIS rate with the corporation's 10 year floating rate that it could get. Are you saying the corporation swaps the O/N OIS against a 10 year version of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overnight_indexed_swap

Comment: Not sure what the Wikipedia article should show? There is no bank and corporation OIS rate. Wikipedia also says the same: "periodic fixed payments are tied to a given fixed rate while the periodic floating payments are tied to a floating rate calculated from a daily compounded overnight rate"

Comment: so the bank dosnt swap rate with the corporation, which has got some rate from somewhere else? it seems as if you say the bank just pays the overnight rate(i.e fed funds) over the course of the loan and the corporation pays the 10 year IOS?

" For example, some bank pay the floating rate a company gets in the market.." as i wrote in the question, is wrong? Can corporations get Fed funds somehow?

Comment: I honestly do not know what else to write and hope someone else answers it in a better way. It is a fixed float swap where the float rate is referencing some OIS / RFR rate (which is the same rate for everyone). No matter who enters this, will swap fixed for float with each other.

Comment: OK. There are two parties. Let call them A(a bank) and B(a compay) . If they swap rates then they must have one rate each. My thinking is that the A has access to O/N FF and can hence roll it for 10y. Hence by taking some risk they can offer B a fixed rate, call it the "10y OIS". B, who has some floating rate from somewhere else, want to swap this rate with that fixed rate A is offering. Is this not how it works?

Comment: No, I think you have a general misunderstanding of  what a swap is. There are no other rates involved. You have two legs.one pays, the other receives.your counterparty has the opposite position. Nothing else involved.if you agree to pay dividends on a swap, you also just pay dividends and not something else. Here your variable reference is an interest rate as opposed to a dividend.

Comment: thanks! I think this is what I wrote boils down to. The company will receive 1.4 %(from the bank who is obligated to pay this) to pay its creditor and the bank will receive the 10 Y OIS rate from the company paying back its creditor and the banks make a spread to between the rate is charged and FF. They swap rates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_swap#/media/File:IRSflows.png