# Substituting the basis swap for the FX forward

Tags: swaps, forward, cross-currency-basis

I have come across [a response](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74024/47484) to the question titled "[Cross currency swap a combination of 2 Interest rate swap](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74011/cross-currency-swap-a-combination-of-2-interest-rate-swap)" on this site. There, it is stated the following:

> Long story short: As @Dimitri Vulis explained, this statement does not
> generally hold, and is at best an approximation. However, this
> [Citibank webpage](https://www.citibank.co.kr/cgrp_pjt/jsp/en/fed/fed040040v.jsp?gnbname=fed) illustrates how you can decompose fixed to fixed
> (FXFX) and fixed to float (FXFL) cross currency swaps into swaps (and
> basis swaps). If you substitute the basis swap for the FX forward, you
> have the decomposition used in your paper.

What does it mean actually? Is a basis swap and FX forward basically the same? How it can be? A basis swap involves float + float rate, but a forward involves only fixed.

Let's be more specific using the screenshot of a Fixed-Floating Cross-currency swap example from the Citibank webpage mentioned in the quote above:

[image]

As it showed, for hedging, Citi-Banking unit (CitiBU) initiates a Float-Float Basis swap with Citi Basis Swap bank (CitiBS). Here I wonder how exactly this basis-swap can be substituted with a Forward?

Let say CF happens in each 3-month, and currently we are at time t=0. So we know how much USD and JPY will be transacted at 3m time. Here I see only risk factor is the Spot FX rate for USD-JPY at 3-month period. I understand that this risk can be hedged with FX Forward. Therefore, for the upcoming CF, this Basis swap can be substituted with FX Forward, which appears to be clear to me.

But what about CFs happening at 6m, 9m,.. period? How excatly Swap-basis CFs at those time-points can be substituted by FX Forwards?

Comment: As.mentioned in the answer, you can use Fwd FX rates (several, for each cashflow) to calculate the implied borrowing cost in another currency. For example, the implied basis can be derived from Covered Interest Rate Parity from making a 3 month EURIBOR loan and converting it into USD via a 3 month FX swap. The difference between the implied cost and the 3m Libor curve is the basis. Nowadays, we are in a post libor world bit the same logic applies to RFR rates.

Comment: @AKdemy Thanks for your response. However I don't think I fully understood such substitution strategy for *all CFs* of Basis-Swap. I have updated my original post with a specific example based on the link provided in the original comment. Appreciate, if you could explain w.r.t. an example (preferably the Citi example which I have added)

Answer (score 3):

It is best to understand this from basic principles.
I will construct these instruments in Python's `rateslib` so that you can also visualise the cashflows and the delta.

#### Calculation Engine

In order to do this we need to set up a framework. This framework will comprise, interest rate curves in EUR and USD and a curve that values EUR cashflows in USD collateral (acting as the basis curve).

```python
from rateslib import *

usdusd = Curve({dt(2023, 1, 1): 1.0, dt(2024, 1, 1): 1.0}, id="usdusd")
eureur = Curve({dt(2023, 1, 1): 1.0, dt(2024, 1, 1): 1.0}, id="eureur")
eurusd = Curve({dt(2023, 1, 1): 1.0, dt(2024, 1, 1): 1.0}, id="eurusd")
fxr = FXRates({"eurusd": 1.10}, settlement=dt(2023, 1, 1))
fxf = FXForwards(
    fx_rates=fxr,
    fx_curves={
        "usdusd": usdusd,
        "eureur": eureur,
        "eurusd": eurusd,
    }
)
```

Next we calibrate our curves so that the 1Y USD swap is 5% the 1Y EUR swap at 3.5% and the cross-currency basis swap is -10bps.

```python
solver = Solver(
    curves=[usdusd, eureur, eurusd],
    instruments=[
        IRS(dt(2023, 1, 1), "1Y", "A", currency="usd", curves="usdusd"),
        IRS(dt(2023, 1, 1), "1Y", "A", currency="eur", curves="eureur"),
        XCS(dt(2023, 1, 1), "1Y", "Q", currency="eur", leg2_currency="usd", curves=["eureur", "eurusd", "usdusd", "usdusd"])
    ],
    s=[5.0, 3.5, -10.0],
    instrument_labels=["1Y USD", "1Y EUR", "1Y EUR/USD"],
    fx=fxf,
)
SUCCESS: `func_tol` reached after 3 iters, `f_val`: 3.96e-17, `time`: 35ms
```

#### 1) The equivalence of `FXSwap` and 2 `FXExchange`s (or forwards)

Next we will show that an `FXSwap` is essentially 2 `FXExchanges`, which are two forward FX transactions.
A market agreed FXSwap contains 4 fixed cashflows. Create a 3M FXSwap and have a look:

```python
fxs = FXSwap(
    effective=dt(2023, 1, 1), 
    terminination="3M", 
    currency="eur", 
    leg2_currency="usd", 
    fx_fixing=1.10, 
    points=42.335246, 
    curves=[None, "eurusd", None, "usdusd"]
)
fxs.cashflows_table(solver=solver)
```

[image]

Now we build the **replicating trades** as 2 `FXExchanges` in the opposite directions.

```python
args = dict(
    currency="eur",
    leg2_currency="usd",
    curves=[None, "eurusd", None, "usdusd"]
)
fxe1 = FXExchange(
    settlement=dt(2023, 1, 1),
    notional=1e6,
    fx_rate=1.10,
    **args
)
fxe2 = FXExchange(
    settlement=dt(2023, 4, 1),
    notional=-1e6,
    fx_rate=1.1042335246,
    **args
)
```

If we add the `FXSwap` and the **replicating** `FXExchanges` to a combined `Portfolio` we can see that all the cashflows and delta risks net out.

```python
pf = Portfolio([fxs, fxe1, fxe2])
pf.cashflows_table(solver=solver)
pf.delta(solver=solver)
```

[image]

[image]

#### 2) The equivalence of an `FXSwap` and a single period `NonMtmFixedFixedXCS`

Now we can show that the 4 cashflows of an `FXSwap` (which is just 2 FX forwards) can replicate a non-mark-to-market fixed-fixed cross-currency swap.

```python
ffxcs = NonMtmFixedFixedXCS(
    effective=dt(2023, 1, 1), 
    termination="3M", 
    frequency="A", 
    currency="eur",
    notional=-1e6,
    leg2_currency="usd", 
    fixed_rate=0.0, 
    leg2_fixed_rate=1.539463,
    fx_fixing=1.10, 
    payment_lag=0,
    curves=[None, "eurusd", None, "usdusd"],
)
```

Since these legs are fixed rate all the cashflows are fixed, again, so we can see the cashflows table:

```python
ffxcs.cashflows_table(solver=solver)
```

[image]

This is the opposite of the original `FXSwap`. If we combine the instruments to a `Portfolio` we see they net out.

```python
pf = Portfolio([fxs, ffxcs])
pf.cashflows_table(solver=solver)
pf.delta(solver=solver)
```

[image]

[image]

#### 3) The Equiavlence of a `NonMtmFixedFixedXCS` with 2 `IRS` and 1 `NonMtmXCS`

So lastly we show that a non-mtm float-float cross-currency swap plus 2 interest rate swaps are equivalently a non-mtm fixed-fixed cross-currency swap.

```python
xcs = NonMtmXCS(
    effective=dt(2023, 1, 1), 
    termination="3M", 
    frequency="A", 
    currency="eur",
    notional=-1e6,
    leg2_currency="usd",  
    fx_fixing=1.10, 
    payment_lag=0,
    curves=["eureur", "eurusd", "usdusd", "usdusd"],
    float_spread=0,
)
eur_irs = IRS(
    effective=dt(2023, 1, 1), 
    termination="3M", 
    frequency="A", 
    notional=-1e6, 
    currency="eur", 
    payment_lag=0, 
    curves=["eureur", "eurusd"], 
    fixed_rate=0.0
)
usd_irs = IRS(
    effective=dt(2023, 1, 1), 
    termination="3M", 
    frequency="A", 
    notional=1.1e6, 
    currency="usd", 
    payment_lag=0, 
    curves=["usdusd", "usdusd"], 
    fixed_rate=1.539463
)

pf = Portfolio([xcs, eur_irs, usd_irs])
pf.cashflows_table(solver=solver)
```

[image]

These are exactly the opposite of the underlying `FXSwap` so when we combine everything, we get a completely cashflow and delta neutral portfolio.

```python
pf = Portfolio([xcs, eur_irs, usd_irs, fxs])
pf.delta(solver=solver).style.format(precision=4)
```

[image]

#### 4) Conclusion

By showing each stage we assert that 2 `FXExchanges` completely replicates 2 single period fixed-float `IRS` in each currency and a single period non-mtm float-float cross-currency basis swap (`NonMtmXCS`).

The pricing parameters on all instruments have been fixed to net out all the cashflows (the `FXExchanges` are at mid market and value to zero).

A string of these such combinations could be used to replicate swaps with more than a single period.

Comment: many thanks for this workout. How can I change above code if I want to replicate this for 1 year swap with 3M cashflow time?

Comment: `frequency="Q",` and `termination="1Y"`