# How does Bloomberg compute the cross currency swap basis?

Tags: swaps, bloomberg, cross-currency-basis, ois-swaps

First, look at the FXFA for EURUSD

The EUR and USD Yield & FX swap rate on **10/18/2023** are given as:
[image]

The computations are shown in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76971/54838).

........................................................................

The second screenshot is
[image]

The original question was:

1 - I would like to ask why coupon rates are different from the FXFA screenshot (EUR and USD Yields)?

2 - Where is the cross currency swap basis? Is the premium the cross currency swap basis?

........................................................................

The amended question looks at the following screenshot from SWPM, which is a EURUSD Cross Currency Swap (1 years)

**10/20/2023-10/20/2024**
[image]

1-How does one calculate the cross currency swap basis SPREAD (-21.311 pips)?

2- Is this the basis spread formula?
[image]

@AKdemy

Comment: As @AKdemy highlights that is not a mkt standard Xccy swap, becuase it is fixed fixed. What is it you are actually trying to derive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second screenshot is not a standard XCCY swap because you look at two fixed rates. You cannot expect that to match the FXFA screen in any case because FXFA uses two floating rates, USD yield and EUR yield. What rates you use in FXFA will be visible when you click on either rates column.

To get a market quote for a cross currency swap, you need to load a float float cross currency swap like the template [I linked](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74024/54838) in the comment for your previous question. It's the old logic of using 3m Libor /Euribor rates instead of SOFR/ESTR but the logic is the same.

Generally, as mentioned in the previous answer, you will not get identical results when comparing FXFA to SWPM.  If you imply the USD rate in FXFA you use FX OTC quotes and back out an implied rate from covered interest rate parity. The basis is the difference to the risk free rate in this case.

In the SWPM case, you look at market quoted swaps and the basis is the quote itself. E.g. for the standard template you get by using `SWPM -FLFL -MTM` you have the underlying ticker `EUXOQQ5 BGN Curncy`. You can also look at quotes on `XCCY`. Right hand side below is the market quote. LHS is the SWPM template.

[image]

Comment: I renewed the question? Could you look at ?