# Test Formula for Cross-Currency Basis by Using S, F and Rates. What Rates to Use?

Tags: interest-rates, fx, market-data, backtesting, cross-currency-basis

I am trying to recreate the charts on slide 6 on the below. Basically "test" the formula for the cross-currency basis for EURUSD. I am using as target EUXOQQ1 BGN Crncy, which is the ESTRON vs SOFR rate 12Month basis, so my goal is to "land" on it, as they do in this presentation [image]

But I am having trouble with the rates to use. Pulling EURUSD spot and 12m forward points to calculate Forward rate is easy enough, but then as far as the interest rates I am striking out - tried SOFR swap, and ESTR swap, and the formulaic basis does not equal the reported, tracked basis EUXOQQ1.

https://docplayer.net/31115498-Cross-currency-basis-swaps-a-primer-june-2015-camille-de-courcel-interest-rate-strategist.html

Comment: You just need to load FXFA and select the curves you desire. See details [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76971/54838) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/77028/54838).

Comment: Since it will all be market quoted data from different sources there is no reason why this should match exactly though.

Comment: Make sure the 1yr rates you are using have identical day count.  Eg Annual act/360.